Should we create a tag for Go Toolchains called go-toolchains?
The tag go-toolchain is about Go toolchains in general (the CLI, using it to do things, etc). I wanted to add a new tag for questions specifically about the feature new in Go 1.21 called Go Toolchains. The tag would be called go-toolchains because it would match the feature's name exactly and wouldn't conflict with the existing go-toolchain tag.
I searched how to add a tag and found an answer suggesting it should be done by editing a question. While attempting to edit a question to add the tag, I got the message:

The tag [go-toolchains] is too similar to [go-toolchain]. If you think this new tag should be allowed, discuss it on meta.

So I created this question here.

We should not.
The plural noun "toolchains" you use to refer to the new feature introduced in Go 1.21 is the same concept that the existing tag go-toolchain identifies, i.e. the Go toolchain.
The Go toolchain is described, quoting the very blog post you linked, as:

[...] the standard library as well as the compiler, assembler, and other tools

The tag wiki excerpt for go-toolchain currently reads:

The Go toolchain is an umbrella term that refers to the Go CLI and its commands, as go run, go build, go test, and so on.

That's exactly the same thing, only taken in different context. As such, it's perfectly valid to use the existing tag for questions about the toolchain directive in go.mod files, the GOTOOLCHAIN environment variable, switching between toolchains, etc.
If you want, you can suggest an edit to the excerpt and/or wiki of go-toolchain to make it clear that the tag covers the new feature introduced in Go 1.21.
